# Built-in (or popular 3rd party library) way to map between primitive and corresponding reference type ("wrapper")?

Tags: java, reflection, types

I'm looking for a bidirectional map that, for example, produces `java.lang.Boolean.class` when a lookup is done on `java.lang.Boolean.TYPE`, and visa versa. Basically, a primitive ⇆ [wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) map.

It seems easy enough to construct such a map, but I'm wondering if one is already available in some popular, common place (this example uses [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)):

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap;

public static final BiMap<Class<?>, Class<?>> PRIMITIVE_TO_OBJECT = ImmutableBiMap.<Class<?>, Class<?>>builder()
    .put(  Boolean.TYPE,   Boolean.class)
    .put(     Byte.TYPE,      Byte.class)
    .put(Character.TYPE, Character.class)
    .put(   Double.TYPE,    Double.class)
    .put(    Float.TYPE,     Float.class)
    .put(  Integer.TYPE,   Integer.class)
    .put(     Long.TYPE,      Long.class)
    .put(    Short.TYPE,     Short.class)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

[org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html) in the [Apache Commons Lang project](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
static Class<?> primitiveToWrapper(Class<?> cls)
    Converts the specified primitive Class object 
    to its corresponding wrapper Class object.

static Class<?> wrapperToPrimitive(Class<?> cls)
    Converts the specified wrapper class to its 
    corresponding primitive class.
```